# Find out battery for Apple Airpods on Ubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, battery, apple

I wish to see my Airpod's battery health when I have it connected to my Kubuntu 20.04, but can't find a command line tool or gui to do so.

I found really old threads about this, nothing very recent.
Does anyone know of any tools or ways to do this?
I'm using KDE.

My system is:

```
$ uname -a
Linux saif-kubuntu 5.4.0-48-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 10 10:58:49 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Other details:

- **Operating System:** Kubuntu 20.04
- **KDE Plasma Version:** 5.18.5
- **KDE Frameworks Version:** 5.68.0
- **Qt Version:** 5.12.8
- **Kernel Version:** 5.4.0-48-generic
- **OS Type:** 64-bit

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you do an ls to the following directory: /sys/class/power_supply/? If so I can show you how to see batt percentage.

Comment: Sure, @SimpliFixed, I see two folders inside the location you gave me, `AC`, and `BATO`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for confirming the directory, first try this with the pods connected via BT, if they are not connected then they will definitely not show up for either of the below:

In newer Ubuntu OS's you can check under All Settings -> Power and see if the pods show up like the keyboard in the screenshot and then set the 2nd option as shown so you can see it in your taskbar, this may or may not work:

[image: All Settings>Power]

If you do not see the pods listed then you can try this using the directory you checked:

You can find useful information under /sys/class/power_supply/. For example the Apple Wireless Keyboard is under /sys/class/power_supply/hid-MAC_HERE-battery/. In the device directory there is a file named capacity, this is the battery in percents.

So for example reading the Apple Wireless Keyboard battery capacity you would:

```
cat /sys/class/power_supply/hid-MAC_HERE-battery/capacity
```

HID being the default for keyboards and mice so you will want to see how your pods show up in the system while connected to BT.

Note that the device type(hid) will change along with the make, while the -batter/capacity should be the same, you will just need to try each one and see which matches your pods with the pods connected via BT to your Ubuntu machine.

Hope the above works for you.

Comment: Sure! Let me try this out and mark this answer if this works for me.

Comment: It will depend if the pods talk to the computer correctly, apple to apple is a bit different compared to apple to linux

Comment: Airpods don't show on this directory. Used this script to check battery status https://github.com/delphiki/AirStatus

Comment: it's not working when I am using ubuntu 20.04